# Check if user chain is available in bash script

Tags: bash, iptables

I have two bash scripts. In the first one a user chain will be created like

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -X STATS
iptables -N STATS
iptables -I INPUT -j STATS
```

In another bash script I will insert the rules like

```
#!/bin/bash

# HERE: If STATS-Chain not available end skript

iptables -A STATS --dport 80
```

How can I check at the position `HERE:` if the STATS-Chain is available?
Is it possible with iptables itself or only with `iptables -L` an some
sed/awk/grep... magic?

Comment: How about `[[ $(iptables -L STAT 2>/dev/null|wc -l) -lt 1 ]] && echo "STAT chain not found. Exiting" && exit` ?

Answer (score 0):

iptables-save output might be easier to grep for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Check if chain STATUS is loaded, if it is exits:

```
/sbin/iptables-save | grep -q '\-A STATUS ' && exit 0
```